# Facebook not showing map for places anymore on iPad

Tags: facebook

Under places in the Facebook app for iPad, I no longer get a mapview as it should be, but rather a listview of the places I have visited. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Logged in with a friends account on the exact same iPad.. It works great, but with my profile the map doesn't show..

Comment: Okay did some more research. Checked my friends profile when I was logged in, still get a listview of places... Logged in with my friends profile, he checked my profile and gets a map view of places... WHAT?!

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if this is the case but sometimes Facebook tests new features and GUI with some users, often without notification. I haven't heard of that being done with places, but it is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: But in my mind : would they really degrade the future ? Removing a map? They would only acheive hate on the internet.